# CalledProcessError in tabula -py with java 1.8

Tags: python, tabula

I am trying to extract table from a pdf using tabula -py in python.But I am getting CalledProcessError

```
from tabula import read_pdf
df=read_pdf("table.pdf",pages="all")

Error:
CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-jar', 
'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\tabula\\tabula-1.0.1-jar- 
with-dependencies.jar', '--pages', 'all', '--guess', 'table.pdf']' returned 
non-zero exit status 2
```

Java Version : 1.8.0_131

OS - windows 7

This question ([tabula-py CalledProcessError: Command '['java', '-jar'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566577/tabula-py-calledprocesserror-command-java-jar)) suggests upgrading to java 1.8.However, I already have java 1.8, but still getting the error.

Any help on this will be really appreciated.
Thanks !

Comment: It might be JAVA PATH problem. Could you upgrade tabula-py and run `import tabula; tabula.environment_info()` ?

Answer (score 0):

This command may create some files in current directory which may not reply in editer.
So I placed the pdf file in the same location where the script was saved 
and it work for me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Pp jym & @chezou for response !

However,the problem happened because java was trying to run a java 7 VM where it found a JRE 8.Steps suggested in the question [Registry key Error: Java version has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697543/registry-key-error-java-version-has-value-1-8-but-1-7-is-required) helped to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Open Run, type 'regedit'
2. go to:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
3. Change the JavaHome and RuntimeLib locations to where your jre is
   installed. (mine was C:\Program Files\Java\jre and C:\Program
   Files\Java\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll respectively)